# VBA autofit from row x onwards?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following vba code to try and set the row auto height in column O.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Missed On Sale").UsedRange.Columns("O:O").EntireRow.AutoFit
```

It works except it affects rows in column O at the top of my sheet which i don't want it to.

---

To overcome this i have tried using this so that it only applies to row 14 downwards.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Missed On Sale").UsedRange.Columns("O14:O200").EntireRow.AutoFit
```

But this kicks out an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Range:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Missed On Sale").Range("O14:O200").EntireRow.AutoFit
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Range` if you are specifying a specific set using both columns and rows :

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Missed On Sale").Range("O14:O200").EntireRow.AutoFit
```

---

BTW, You can use `Sheets` instead of `Worksheets` and when you do something like :

```
Sheets(1).Range("B2:K11").Range("A1")
```

this will in fact, refer to B2 in that sheet.

So luckily, `UsedRange` every often starts at A1, so your :

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Missed On Sale").UsedRange.Columns("O:O")
```

is the same as (if you used A1 or anything in both Col A and Row 1) :

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Missed On Sale").Columns("O:O")
```

Comment: beat you by 30 seconds. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner : ^^ I saw that when my answer appeared! T_T

Comment: @ScottCraner: `UsedRange` is not always starting at A1. Create a blank Worksheet, enter something just in B2 and enter `? activesheet.UsedRange.address` in Immediate Window. It will show `$B$2`

Comment: @FunThomas It was not me but R3uk that made that statement.

Comment: @ScottCraner Right, sorry to mix you up with R3uK - you were the fast one ;-)

Comment: @FunThomas I find it an honor to be confused with R3uk, but I think R3uk may take offense being compared to me. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner : You are being far too modest, the honor is ofc for me! ;)

Comment: @FunThomas : I'd thought so but didn't take time to check, I'm editing to reflect that!